# how to parse/see the data in siena datastore?

Tags: playframework, siena

While playing around with playframework yabe-siena-gae, I noticed a datastore file created for the sample data.

Does any tool exist or is there some way to view the data inside the datastore file created by siena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the out of the box Play Server with the Google App Engine module, then you can't unfortunately.

See [here for more details](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/3IgBfnH6Bm4).

The post does suggest that if you are deploying to a local servlet container (i.e. Tomcat/JBoss, but not the Play Netty server) then you may be able to use the standard data viewer URL that comes with GAE

```
localhost:8080/_ah/admin/
```

Alternatively, deploy a test version to a GAE account, and use the data viewer from within the google web consoles for managing your apps.

Answer (score 1):

Codemwnci is right.
You can also try the [play-crud-siena](http://www.playframework.org/modules/crudsiena) module for Play1.x which allows to see the data in your tables by just adding a few controllers to your application.
It's not perfect but it's better than nothing.
If you use Siena+Sql, you can use the traditional tools associated with your RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks! @mandubian for your play-crud-siena module. it is cool!.

Comment: you're welcome! I hope that for play2, we'll be able to provide even better things ;)